# Running aspell in emacs with aspell key bindings

Tags: ispell, spell-checking

I am using `aspell` on the (Linux) command line, and have also started using it with `mu4e` in emacs to spell-check my composed messages using `ispell-message`.  That command runs `aspell`, but with `ispell` key bindings, which I find confusing (in particular if `a` means `add` in the one and `ignore` in the other, while `i` means `ignore` in the one and `add` in the other).  Is there a way to run `aspell` in emacs with `aspell` key bindings?

(Running `aspell` with `ispell` key bindings in the terminal is easier, but has the effect that I make mistakes there too...  I also know I should move to `hunspell`, but I have to resolve another issue there first).

Comment: You would need to edit the function `ispell-command-loop` inside `ispell.el` -- look for things like `(= char ?a)`, `(= char ?i)`, and pay attention to `command-characters` defined at the outset.  These are not the type of questions I generally answer because people prefer fixes using `advice` rather than editing a core function directly, or creating an entirely new function with the edits.

Comment: I had hoped to change keybindings with some option or changing some variables.  I don't know `advice`, but I'll look into it - it sounds like a more sustainable way to achieve my goal than editing .el files after every update.